# Search for string in WordPress site with PHP and replace with new string

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this WordPress site. When DOM is loaded, I have this element.

```
<div class="agents-usp">
  <p>Search through more than 1,300 shipments including:</p>
</div>
```

I would like to replace 1,300 with 1,600 before the DOM is loaded. Is this possible with PHP?

I have tried something with .str_replace() method.

```
$text = str_replace('1,300', '1,600', $text);
```

Not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding this to functions.php:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply'); 
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply'); 
    function translate_reply($translated) { 
        $translated = str_ireplace('1,300', '1,600', $translated);     
    return $translated; 
}
```

Works for WordPress!

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var strNewString = jQuery('.agents-usp').html().replace(/1,300/g,'1,600');
jQuery('.agents-usp').html(strNewString);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="agents-usp">
  <p>Search through more than 1,300 shipments including:</p>
</div>
```